# FourSquare Real-Time Push API return NULL value

Tags: c#-4.0, real-time, foursquare

I have set up the Push URL for my app for "Push Checkin's by this consumer's users" and my link is "https://foursquareapi.pureprofile.com/FourSquare/FourSquareRealTimeUpdate".
Even, I am getting an response from your end where it's value is NULL. I am getting object value like "{"id":null,"createdAt":null,"
type":null,"timeZone":null,"user":null,"venue":null}".

You can see id, createdAt, type, timeZone, user, venue  value NULL.

Comment: The above link code is detailed below:-

using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace com.pureprofile.socialnetwork.Controllers
{
public class FourSquareController : Controller
{
[HttpPost]
public string FourSquareRealTimeUpdate(FourSquareRealTime obj)
{
string reply = "0";
string JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
reply=ppSite.APIWrapper.Team.SocialNetwork.SocialNetworks.FourSquareRealTimeUpdates(JsonData);
return reply;
}
}
}

Comment: What do you get before parsing the data? What is the raw push data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....the issue has been resolved.